# 'Xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' to the template of bottle How to hand it over?

Tags: python, bottle

**Browser error display**

```
 Error: 500 Internal Server Error Unsupported response type: <class
 Unsupported response type: <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
```

**Apache error log**

```
[error] [client ] TypeError: Object of type 'Element' is not JSON serializable
[error] [client ] TypeError: Object of type 'ElementTree' is not JSON serializable
```

---

**Code that I tried but I can not get the expected result**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from bottle import route, view

@route('/')
@view("hoge_template")
def hoge():
  tree = ElementTree.parse('rss-2.0.xml')
  root = tree.getroot()
  return(root)
  #return dict(root=root)
```

---

**Environment**

・Python 3.6

・Bottle 0.13

・mod_wsgi

・Chrome

---

**How can I display all the contents of a loop in a bottle?**

```
root = tree.getroot()
for item in root.findall('channel/item'):
    title = item.find('title').text
    url = item.find('link').text
    return(url, title)
```

Comment: I believe bottle views are supposed to return _text_.  So you could `return root.tostring()` (although in that case, I would wonder why you're bothering to parse the xml file at all; it would be much simpler to just open the file, get its content, and return it.)

Comment: I tried root.tostring().But AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'tostring'..I add question.